# The workflow that should be executed after automatically creating a pull request is not executed

Tags: github, github-actions, pull-request

I created a workflow using the actions `repo-sync/pull-request`, but the workflow I already created is no longer executed.

Workflow that is executed when pull_request is created in develop and main. An example is shown below.

```yaml
name: example

on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: ["Create Pull Request"]
    types:
      - completed
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main
      - develop

jobs:
...
```

The workflow using `repo-sync/pull-request` looks like this.

```yaml
name: Create Pull Request

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - feature/*

jobs:
  create-pull-request:
    name: create-pull-request
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Create Pull Request
        id: open-pr
        uses: repo-sync/pull-request@v2
        with:
          destination_branch: "develop"
          pr_title: "[example] test_summary"
          pr_body: "test body."
          github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

If you know any solution, please let me know.

I look forward to working with you : )

Comment: Could give more details about what you want to achieve exactly? Do you want the `Create Pull Request` workflow to start the `example` one? Or is it something else?

Comment: I'm sorry. Originally, it is assumed that "example" is also executed after "Create Pull Request" is executed, but since it is not said to be this description, I asked what is wrong.

Comment: Your `Create Pull Request` workflow will always trigger when pushing something to a branch named `feature/*`. Your `example` workflow will trigger when the `Create Pull Request` workflow is completed OR when you PR to `main` or `develop` branches. Is it the behaviour you want to achieve, or would like it to work a different way?

Comment: There was official documentation on this behavior. https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#triggering-new-workflows-using-a-personal-access-token

Comment: Ok, so to resolve your problem you would just have to substitute the `${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}` for a [PAT secret](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) (adding it to the repository) an using for example `${{ secrets.PAT }}` instead in your workflow.